# Send multiple identical messages with GCM

Tags: sms, google-cloud-messaging

My question is about google cloud Messaging system for sending huge amounts of sms to different targets but the text of messages is identical. Is there any spam filtering by google that may deny the delivery of my sms to those targets?

Comment: I don't think there is spam filtering by default but there is lots of app to do that

Comment: GCM only delivers push notifications over data connection, you can't send sms using it